# Numbering tables sequentially

Tags: tables, counters, cleveref

I would like to number my table so that I have, e.g.

```
Theorem 1.3

Table 1.4

Lemma 1.5
```

How can I achieve this result? I am also using cleveref, so ideally `\cref{ThatTable}` would produce a linked ``Table 1.4'' when I am done as well.

Comment: This requires either a common counter for theorems, lemma and tables or another, more sophisticated approach. Please provide a MWE in order to get some quick help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do nothing particular: `\newtheorem{theorem}[table]{Theorem}` will do.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}[table]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My content}

\begin{theorem}\label{A}
\end{theorem}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A dummy table}\label{B}
\end{table}

\begin{theorem}\label{C}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

See \cref{A}, \cref{B}, \cref{C}.

\begin{table}
  \caption{Another dummy table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note, however, that the floating nature of `table` may make the output to appear “out of sync”.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this. `LaTeX Error: Command \theorem already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` It seems to be in part because I have this: `\newtheorem{theorem}[thm]{Theorem}`. But if I remove that, the document doesn't seem to know what a Theorem is anymore.

Comment: @jdc Not with my example.

Comment: Yes, your example, all alone, does the right thing, but sadly, I am unable to integrate into my existing code in a way that doesn't give an error. I was wondering if you had any advice on how I can fix this problem. If not, I understand; in any event, I didn't mean to cast aspersions on your example, which works beautifully.

Comment: @jdc Sorry, but without seeing the code and the setup it's impossible to say anything sensible. Open a new question, with a MWE.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved with the mutally assignment of associated counters (package `assoccnt` or `xassoccnt`)

Each time `Theorem` is increased, the table counter should be increased as well and vice versa, the `lemma` environment uses the `Theorem` counter, so this will be increased too.

The usage of this continous counting should prevent floating tables, as those might 'interrupt' the counting

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{assoccnt}


\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[Theorem]{lemma}


\DeclareAssociatedCounters{Theorem}{table}%
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{Theorem}%   



\begin{document}
\chapter{My content}

\begin{Theorem}
\end{Theorem}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A dummy table}
\end{table}


\begin{Theorem}
\end{Theorem}


\begin{Theorem}
\end{Theorem}



\begin{table}
  \caption{Another dummy table}
\end{table}

\begin{lemma}
 First lemma
\end{lemma}


\begin{table}
  \caption{Another dummy table}
\end{table}

\begin{Theorem}
\end{Theorem}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\cref` works as expected