# I would like to define or redefine the `thm` environment

Tags: theorems

Pursuant to the answer to my question at [An error I get trying to number tables consecutively with theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218007/an-error-i-get-trying-to-number-tables-consecutively-with-theorems),
I can number tables and theorems consecutively without anything breaking. I would like to also have a `thm` environment, functionally the same as `theorem` but easier to type, which is also numbered the same way tables are. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\newtheorem{thm}[table]{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Running this code tells me that `thm` is already defined, but on the other hand, if I excise the `\newtheorem` line, I'm instead warned that `thm` is not defined. It seems like I just can't win. What to do?

P.S.: The code compiles and complies without complaint if I remove the `thmtools` package; however, I do need `thmtools` for my real document.

Comment: why not just name your new theorem type something else: `\newtheorem{tbthm}[table]{Theorem}`?  that's why differently named theorem environments are permitted, even encouraged.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I'm not sure I understand the question; I did it because I didn't want there to be any theorem type that *wasn't* enumerated sequentially with tables. It seems a bit clunky to make *every* theorem technically of the table type, if that's what's going on, but that was the suggestion I got, and I'm (obviously) not that good at TeX, so ...

Comment: since `thm` is already defined, and defining theorems isn't done with `\newcommand` or `\newenvironment`, you really do need to give it a different name.  that is what @yo' has done.  then `\let` lets you use the same name without *technical* conflict; just be sure that you never want to use the original meaning again, and also observe that, since `thm` is an environment, both the beginning and end must be taken care of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the purpose of having Theorems use the `table` counter, but that's not my business. The work around this is to define another environment and then "map it":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\newtheorem{abcthm}[table]{Theorem}
\let\thm\abcthm
\let\endthm\endabcthm

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's the way I was taught to make tables and theorems be numbered consecutively. Thanks for this workaround. I should apparently learn a bit more about `\let`. It seems very useful for fixing this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to conform to the usage/interface provided by [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools). Instead of `\newtheorem` you need to use `\declaretheorem[<opts>]{<theorem>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

If you must, you can use the following interface:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}
```

Comment: Oh dear. I actually don't seem to have any `\declaretheorem`s remaining. Maybe I'm not using `thmtools` for anything after all anymore. Hmm...